# Issue with odeint from scipy.integrate when I start the range not at 0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I am writing a program to solve a differential equation in the form x''(t) + w^2(t)*x(t) = 0 so i used odeint. However, whenever it doesn't start from 0, it puts the first point as to what 0 should have been

[sin(t) when starting from t = -1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86LsN.png)

[sin(t) when starting from t = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMIsF.png)

the pictures show the issues clearly

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint


def omega(t):
    return 1


def dU_dt(U, t):
    return [U[1], -U[0] * ((omega(t)) ** 2)]


x0 = 0  # This is the initial condition x(0)
x1 = 1  # This is the initial condition x'(0)

U0 = [x0, x1]

pi = np.pi

start = -1
stop = 2 * pi
N = 10 ** 2

xs = np.linspace(start, stop, N)
Us, info = odeint(dU_dt, U0, xs, rtol=1e-10, full_output=True)
ys = Us[:, 0]

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.axvline(x=0.0, color=(0, 0, 0))
plt.axhline(y=0.0, color=(0, 0, 0))
plt.plot(xs, ys)

for i in range(len(xs)):
    print(xs[i], ys[i])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The "initial condition" does not mean the value at t=0.  The initial condition given to `odeint` is the value at the first `t` value.  In your case, you have `start = -1`, so your `U0` specifies the value at t=-1.  That's what is shown in your first plot.

Comment: Is there a way to always use x(0) and x'(0) despite starting at other values.